# Get sum from a DataColumn values in C#

Tags: c#, sum, datacolumn

I have a table in a `dataadapter`. I want to get the count and sum of a specific column of it. How is that possible?

- This is the code for reach to the column, what after that?

  DataColumn buy_count = myDataSet.Tables["all_saled"].Columns["how_much_buy"]

I know that we have sum, count,... in SQL, but how can I do it in C#?

Answer (score 6):

You can use LINQ to DataSets

```
var sales = myDataSet.Tables["all_saled"].AsEnumerable();

var buy_total = sales.Sum(datarow => datarow.Field<int>("how_much_buy"));
```

[Check the LINQ to DataSets 101 Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688086)

P.S. might need the **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** assembly referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DataTable.Compute` method:

```
int total = (int)myDataSet.Tables["all_saled"].Compute("SUM(how_much_buy)", null);
```

Comment: Compute method need two argument : string expression and string filter in C# winform

Comment: here is complete sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @hamze, yes, I forgot the second parameter; it's fixed now

Comment: Both answers are nice, but I would go for the LINQ one, it reads "cleaner"imo