# Sum datagridview value including decimal c#

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I achieve to get sum result including the decimal point,
here is what I tried

```
// int sum;
decimal sum = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value));
    //sum1 = sum.ToString("N");
    //TotalAmount.Text = Math.Round(double.Parse(sum), 2).ToString();
}
//TotalAmount.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", sum);
TotalAmount.Text = Math.Round(sum,2).ToString();
```

Comment: Why do you use `Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value))`? Just use `Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value)` instead of `Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[6].Value))`.

Comment: If your `DataGridView`'s datasource is bound to a `DataTable` or `DataSet`, it's better to sum from underlying datasource. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707290/get-sum-from-a-datacolumn-values-in-c-sharp)

Comment: lliar appreciate the correction you made.. but ive get same result in the totalamount.text instead of 123.12345 it roundup into 1234.00, gridview data is coming from other form not on my dbase as datasource..

Comment: Then I that suspect that data in the DataGrid is of integer type. Therefore you get integer value without decimal part. Try to check the type of the data in the DataGrid using debug.

Comment: lliar, thank you.. problem solve, upon checking the entire code process, found out that there is if statement that re-convert the result into int reason to roundup..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have datasource bound to datagridview then try to sum it on the datasource otherwise u can use the following query too to get sum

```
dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(x=>Convert.ToDecimal(x.Cells[6].Value));
```